# Change Text of Array Of links in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my school's website they have a dropdown list of courses that you're currently enrolled in on the home page. However, if you see it, it is cluttered full of letters that many people might not want to see.

I already know how I'm going to do this. I'm going to use jQuery to select each list item:

```
var links = $(".d2l-datalist li .d2l-course-selector-item .d2l-left .vui-link");
```

This returns an array of `<a>` elements in text form.

Using `links.text("Boo!");` I can set the text of all of them to "Boo!", but I want to change each one individually, using a for/in loop to itterate through each `<a>` and change the text depending on what the value of the `href` is.

However, whenever I do this, since the items in the array are strings, I cannot do anything to them with jQuery.

Any help with this is appreciated :)

Here's my code so far (running from a `$.getScript()` from a JS bookmarklet):

```
var links = $(".d2l-datalist li .d2l-course-selector-item .d2l-left .vui-link");
//links.text("Boo!");

var count = 1;
for (var link in links) {
    link.text("Boo #" + count);
    count += 1;
}
```

Relevant markup: http://hastebin.com/ulijefiqaz.scala

Comment: include all relevant code to OP

Comment: Two things-- the relevant markup would be helpful as well.  Also: `for...in` loops should really only be used to iterate over keys in an object.  If you are iterating over an array, you should really be using a standard `for` loop.  Also, since it's an array, you could also just use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)...

Comment: @anied I'm used to using python's for/in loops so that didn't really occur to me. What would the benefits be of using forEach over for/in? Also I added a hastebin link to the relevant markup.

Comment: @RedXTech - forEach is a syntax some people prefer as it allows you to use a function (although it is difficult/impossible to `break;` from.  But more importantly, you _should not_ use `for...in` loops to iterate over an array-- it [can yield problematic results](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)...

Comment: @anied ah ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) **iterator function**.

```
var links = $(".d2l-datalist li .d2l-course-selector-item .d2l-left .vui-link");

var count = 1;

links.each(function() {
    $(this).text("Boo #" + count++);
});
```

Comment: Basic tests have worked so far, will accept once I test the main features :)